# Have unique set of name without blank sheet name in array using app script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a unique sheet name using an array format in the app script, this is the so far that I have come. The array has a blank sheet name also which is getting created as a new sheet every time the code runs along with a sheet that has a unique sheet name.
I have runner the console log and found the array is capturing the blank sheet as well from the source spreadsheet name
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXmVO.png)

```js
function createSheet(){
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sourceWs =ss.getSheetByName("PCR sheet");//This is the base sheet which has the data to capture and filter

const vendorName =sourceWs.
getRange(3,2,sourceWs.getLastRow()-2,1).
getValues().
map(vn =>vn[0]);

const uniqueVendorName = [ ...new Set(vendorName) ];//This is where the unique data is getting captured along with blank sheet name
console.log(uniqueVendorName);

const currentSheetNames = ss.getSheets().map( s => s.getName());

let ws;
uniqueVendorName.forEach(vendorName=> {
        if(!currentSheetNames.includes(vendorName)){
        ws = null;  
        ws = ss.insertSheet();
        ws.setName(vendorName);
        ws.getRange("A2").setFormula(`=FILTER('PCR Sheet'!A3:J,'PCR Sheet'!B3:B="${vendorName}")`); // This creates multiple sheet based on unique value on colum no 2 using pcr sheet.
        sourceWs.getRange("A2:J2").copyTo(ws.getRange("A1:J1"));//Header gets fixed for all pages
        
    
    } //if vendor name doesnot exist

}); //ForEach trough the list of vendor

}//close createsheet function
```

How to remove it and run the code without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that in your script, the empty value is included in `[ ...new Set(vendorName) ]`. So, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const uniqueVendorName = [ ...new Set(vendorName) ];
```

#### To:

```
const uniqueVendorName = [...new Set(vendorName)].filter(String);
```

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)